How do I position content inside of a tikzpicture?
I'm working on a system where I want to draw a rectangle and the build the contents of that rectangle. I'm using tikz to draw a dashed rectangle but I'm having a really difficult time positioning the content inside of the drawn rectangle. Here is a minimal example of the problem I'm running up against:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[dashed] (0, 0) rectangle node{this text is centered but I want it at the top left} (4.4in, 2.25in);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \vspace{1cm}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[dashed] (0, 0) rectangle (4.4in, 2.25in);
        \node at (0,0) {this text is centered at the bottom left and not fully in the container};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[dashed] (0, 0) rectangle (4.4in, 2.25in);
        \node at (4,5.5) {this text is where I want it, but this is brute force};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Which generates this:

Is there a way that I can consistently position the content starting at the top left of the frame without having to brute-force the coordinates? I don't see anything mentioned in the documentation about this. I'm open to solutions that don't use TikZ if there is a better way to do this. The actual content I'm putting in these rectangles is much more complex, if that matters. Notably, it is not a picture.

Welcome to tex.sx.

I don't know if I understood your problem correctly.
Here is what I understand:
In a rectangle, the node, if written between the coordinates, is always placed in the center of the rectangle (middle of the coordinates). To place it next to the top left vertex, this vertex only needs to be the first coordinate.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[dashed] (0, 2.25in)  node[anchor=north west]{this text is centered but I want it at the top left}rectangle (4.4in, 0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

In case you want more than one line of text.  Note that the text area is 2.25in by 4.4in, but the dashed box is slightly larger (0.666em + 0.8pt for the bounding box).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}% radnom text

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[outline/.style={draw=black,dashed}]
        \node[outline]{\parbox[c][2.35in][t]{4.4in}{\blindtext}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


You can also impose a width on the node text, for example:  text width=4.3 in

@AndréC - You can also impose a height, but the text will be centered (vertically).  [align=left] can be implemented either as a tabular or as \Raggedright.

I simply mean that by imposing a width on the text with the text width option for the node, it produces the same result as your \parbox.

Yes, albeit with less control.  In fact, I am pretty sure that TikZ implements text width by using a \parbox internally.  Why re-invent the wheel?

It's possible, but you'd have to look at the source code.

Actually, TikZ is written in plain TeX, so it would more likely be \vcenter with \hsize set by text width.

The question deserves to be asked in chat. TeX, LaTeX and Friends
